# saving a function that uses a library with dill

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I want to save a function using dill.

This function is using a function from a specific library (e.g re)

To save the dill/pickle file, I use the following :

```
import dill
import re

def fct(a):
    #The function uses the re library
    return ...

filename = 'test.pickle'
dill.dump(fct, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

However, when I try to load this function on a different notebook (using dill.load), I got the following error:

```
name 're' is not defined
```

I am guessing that dill.dump did not save the import with the function, how could I solve that? I tried including the import inside the function but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following in the first script before dumping the function in the dill file seems to work :

```
dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```